# how big of a issue is screen resolution with android development

Tags: java, android

I'm getting into app/game development for android and I just wanted to know how hard it is to make your games work with all phones. or do the phones just scale the app to fit with the screens? thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

Screen resolution isn't as big a problem as the differences in screen ratios and defining things like touch-area sizes.

The commonest devices that my games and apps are running on have the following sizes...

320x480 (4x6)
480x800 (3x5)
480x854 (it defies belief to try to give a ratio to that nonsense)

I use AndEngine and libgdx - both will scale automatically BUT I have to choose a ratio to work with and it will crop (with black bars rather than lost content) on devices which don't share that ratio (for reference I choose to crop lower-resolutions as I think people with nicer screens would complain sooner!!)

Actual physical screen sizes vary too - and you have to bear-in-mind that a box which may seem big enough to hit on a 4.3" high-density phone could be near-impossible to hit on a smaller/lower-density device...

Both of those things are far more worrying than scaling...

Comment: is there any way to emulate different screen sizes and resolutions? I only have 1 droid phone.

Comment: your emulator is a great help. you can customize your emulator as u needed from avd manager.

Comment: As PH7 says, you can use the emulator to test this stuff.  The only snag is that the emulators performance is APPALLING, you need a really, really decent PC to run it - older PCs, laptops, netbooks will struggle with it (netbooks probably won't even start it)

Answer (score 0):

You should remember that screen resolution is only one of many factors deciding about game compatibility.
I think this video is a good for start 
http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/building-aggressively-compatible-android-games.html